# Finding the SQL output of a parameterized query

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameterized-query

I'm making a parameterized query using C# against a SQL server 2005 instance, and I'd like to take a look at the SQL that is run against the database for debugging purposes. Is there somewhere I can look to see what the output SQL of the parameterized command is, either in the database logs or in the Visual Studio debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SQL Server Profiler to view the sql

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/sql_server_profiler.asp

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929(SQL.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

SQL Profiler is the best solution, but if you need something more organic to your application that you could deploy and enable/disable in production, QA, etc... then you could build a wrapper around the System.Data.SqlClient Provider (*Ex. the provider registered in the config file as... providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"*).

This would essentially act like an intercept proxy which would give you access to all the information passing through the Provider (e.g. between your application and the database client). This would allow you to siphon-off what you need, intercept, modify, aggregate and/or enrich it. This is a bit more advanced but opens the door to capture a whole range of information and could be inserted/replaced/removed as a separate layer of concern.